# What technologies are available for client side interactive data grid like UIs?

Tags: jquery, css, browser, datagrid

I am currently working on a project for which we have developed very interactive data grid control using HTML, CSS and JavaScript(custom as well as JQuery). This all seems to be fine on high end client machines but our customer is complaining that the browsers are taking very long time to render the received data.

We have noticed that typically a page is getting loaded and rendered in 1-2 seconds in almost all main stream browers running on win2k3 server with 3 Gig RAM and one 3 GHz processor but our customer has calculations going upto 25 seconds.

My questions is basically that what are the options available if we want to use some other technology to speed up the rendering of pages with such interactive data grids where user can dynamically select the available columns in the data table and can pass client side events(javascript calls) to other flash contents on the same page. Thanks in advance.

Comment: Is it slow because of too much data (slow connection) or too much logic (slow computer)?

Comment: @SLaks `render the received data`, so I assume b.

Comment: @SLaks yes it seems to be the javascript logic. Mostly a for loop which hides a few columns using the jQuery selector for an attribute i.e.

for (c in columns)
{
    var selectorClass = "selector_" + columns[c];
    $("[colClass='class_header_" + columns[c] + "']").hide();
    $("[colClass='class_data_" + columns[c] + "']").hide();
}

Let me know if such a thing is possible using any other faster technology than javascript without using any other third party plugins for browsers.

Comment: You can optimize your Javascript and make it quite a bit faster.  For example, you're parsing that complex selector too many times.

Answer (score 1):

[jqGrid](http://www.trirand.com/blog/) is my goto for this. The developer has spent a lot of time optimizing it for huge datasets.

Answer (score 1):

I use [DataTables](http://datatables.net) for this, but I have to admit that most of the performance benefit is down to delegating heavy tasks (sorting, filtering) to the server-side, which has a MySQL database to handle the data. The client side only ever receives X number of records (200 or less) at a time, which is a trivial amount for most machines to process.

All that to say, I'm not sure what its performance is like with thousands of records in the page, but based on forum posts on their site, it seems to handle at least hundreds of records without blinking.

Which I suppose raises another question: do you have the full data set in the client side and perform sorts/filters on it in the client? With or without DataTables, you will probably want the server to do the heavy lifting. With an existing plugin or with your own custom code, leveraging Ajax and a data interchange format (JSON is an obvious choice) will facilitate this.

Not ready for primetime yet, but worth keeping an eye on jQuery UI Grid. Recent blog post from the team: http://blog.jqueryui.com/2011/10/state-of-the-jquery-ui-grid/

Comment: Thanks for your response Greg. As a matter of fact these dynamic datagrids are showing (and need to show) only a few rows 5-12 with 40-45 columns. All columns are loaded in the table by server and then using JavaScript we hide most of them on client side and show only a few most relevant. This hiding activity seems to be taking most of the time during rendering on slow machines.

Comment: That is a tiny amount of data! I couldn't even guess at what (if any) inefficiencies there might be, but 25 seconds of processing is shocking to me, even on an old machine. Good luck with testing the other options; maybe jqGrid of DataTables will provide what you need!

Comment: @SalmanQ, try to use native css to show/hide irrelevant entries (eg by adding a css-class), it should speed things up considerably. Also try to synchronise the show/hiding process with the browser's animationFrame (eg by using requestAnimationFrame or sth similar)